# Preposition usage, "for" vs "in", in the context of a "For the purpose of * in/of *"

Tags: prepositions

I'm preparing the title of my PhD dissertation and have lost confidence in the use of my prepositions.

- The *title* is "A Study on the Near-Surface Flow and Acoustic
  Emissions of Trailing Edge Serrations"
- The *subtitle* is "for the
  purpose of noise reduction **in** wind turbine blades".

Suddenly that last "**in**" feels like it could be "**of**" (despite feeling it would lose some nicety in how it sounds).

What do you think is grammatically correct though?

Comment: If the sentence were written "for the purpose of reducing noise in wind turbine blades," there would be no question of substituting "of," unless you put "the" in front of "noise."  Grammatically, you could probably use "of" in the original sentence, but then you'd have four "of's."

Answer (score 1):

One of the **functions** of the preposition **of** is to identify abstract nouns by their sound  source.

Ex. I heard the bark of a dog.
bark= noun
source=dog

In your sentence the noun =noise (modified as reduced noise) and the source is the turbine.

I hope that helps.